# How do you pass JSON content on a response, when using pushState or PJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, pushstate, pjax

When using `pushState`, or more specifically, a PJAX library like Defunkt's [jquery-pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/) plugin, how should you send back JSON data in the response in addition to the HTML fragment? Or should you at all?

For example, is it appropriate to send the JSON in a (custom) response header, e.g. `X-JSON-RESPONSE`? Or should you make separate asynchronous calls to the server after the HTML fragment is returned by which the necessary JSON content is retrieved and loaded? Is there another option I'm not thinking of?

Comment: What's your ultimate goal here? Are you trying to send HTML in the body with the same HTML as json in a header? Are you trying to send extra information about the HTML as a header?

Comment: @alpha1 The aim here is not only to return the HTML fragment response, but to also return relevant JSON content/data along with that response, if possible, in an attempt to avoid additional requests to the server. This is assuming that the JSON data being returned in addition to the HTML fragment is able to be served together in the same request.

Comment: why not return a json array with multiple parts and sort them as needed. Decode each array item as id=>html fragment.

Comment: That may work; returning the HTML fragment as part of a JSON array in addition to other JSON data. Though I'm not sure how it will interact with the PJAX library above. Going that route I might need to roll my own solution. Cheers.